# .each() function does not loop through my object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery function and it seems that the .each function never loop through my object (it goes right to the "$("#AppConnect").val(appConnectString);" line without iterating).

Here's the code :

```
$("input").focusin(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("appConnectData")) {
        var key, value, appConnectString = "";
        $(".appConnectData").each(function (index, element) {
            if ($(element).hasClass("key")) {
                key = $(element).val();
            } else {
                value = $(element).val();
            }
            if (!key && !value) {
                appConnectString += key + "." + value + ";";
            }
        });

        $("#AppConnect").val(appConnectString);
    }
    //alert($("#AppConnect").val());
});
```

What I've done to find the problem with no success so far :

- Check if the $(".appConnectData") is empty
- Check the .each syntax (you never know :p)
- Insert a breakpoint to see if I have some errors
- Put the content of $(".appConnectData") in a var and then loop through the said var

Maybe it is because my .each is inside a focusin function, or maybe I did something else wrong but I can't seem to find what.

I thank you all in advance for the help provided :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `if` condition, you should check `key && value` if you want to make sure `key` & `value` has a value.

```
if (key && value) {
    appConnectString += key + "." + value + ";";
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rbu1b27d/)

Comment: @Yaji can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rbu1b27d/1/) to recreate the issue

Comment: Thank you it works now I think I need to review logical operators x)

Comment: in each case, if key exists then value will not exist so the correct logical operator would be `or`. even this is not enough

Answer (score 0):

In each case, if `key` exists then `value` will not exist and vice-versa. so the correct logical operator would be `or`. even this is not enough!

You can separate `if` to test both key and value existence:

```
  $("input").focusin(function () {
if (!$(this).hasClass("appConnectData")) {
    var key, value, appConnectString = "";
    $(".appConnectData").each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).hasClass("key")) {
            key = $(element).val();
        } else {
            value = $(element).val();
        }
        if (key) {
            appConnectString += key".";
        }
        if(value){
           appConnectString +=value;
        }
        if(key||value){              
           appConnectString +=";";
        }
    });

    $("#AppConnect").val(appConnectString);
  }
  //alert($("#AppConnect").val());
});
```